# CakePHP contain condition cannot use variable?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I guess there is an easy solution for this issue, but i cant seem to find it out. I get back an error saying $p_name equals NULL on the contain Comments query. How is this possible since it was clearly set before.

```
$p_name = "Berta";

$query = $articles->find()->contain([
    'Comments' => function ($q) {
       return $q
            ->select(['name'])
            ->where(['Comments.name' => $p_name]);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is not available inside the scope of function q, you need to pass with the USE construct like:

```
$p_name = "Berta";

$query = $articles->find()->contain([
    'Comments' => function ($q) use ($p_name) {
       return $q
            ->select(['name'])
            ->where(['Comments.name' => $p_name]);
    }
]);
```

Comment: Genious! That's the answer, will mark in 2 minutes!

Comment: Note that this is not a CakePHP thing, it's a PHP thing. See example 3 in the [anonymous functions documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).